# Como puedo hacer para que está lista me abrá unicamente 1 y las otras listas se vayan cerrando

Tags: javascript, html

Me podrían ayudar como puedo hacer que esté JS Pueda darme una condición de que al momento selecciones un solo sub menú en este caso 2 de aquí se abra y que al momento de seleccionar otro sub menú me lo cierre el que ya había abierto con anterioridad.
Las clases de nav-links es el estilo que se le da CSS para que esté acomodado de forma de un sidebar
arrow2 activa la función de mostras las sublistas que desea seleccionar por medio de un icono (i) pero me gustaría que al momento de que abra una sub-menú esté despliegue 1 sub lista y que si seleccione otra me lo cierre, y tengo otro problema no se si alguien pueda ayudarme a que en ves de identificar a solo el Icono Arrow me identifique toda la etiqueta A y  me pueda hacer la misma acción que hace el icono de arrow de mostrarme el sub menu de la opción seleccionada.

```
<ul class="nav-links"> 
      <li class="active arrow2">
        <div class="iocn-link">
          <a href="#">
       <span class="link_name">Página de Inicio</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow'></i>
        </div>
        
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Página de Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Resumen de Actividad</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Editar Perfil</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Suscripciones</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cambiar contraseñas</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

       <li>
        <div class="iocn-link">
          <a href="#"> 
            <span class="link_name" >Página Web</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Página Web</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Selección de Plantilla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portada Banners</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portada - Contenido</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Distribución de Portada</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Páginas estáticas</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Redes Sociales</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gestión SEO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Configuración Sitio Web</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>


<script>
  let arrow2 = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
  for (var i = 0; i < arrow2.length; i++) {
    arrow2[i].addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
   let arrow2Parent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
   arrow2Parent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
   
    });
  }
</script>



 .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 260px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.close {
    width: 78px;
}

.sidebar .Logo img {
    margin: 45px 0 10px -10px;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.sidebar .logo-details i {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #777777;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-width: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.sidebar .logo-details i:hover{
    color:;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #6e6b7b;
  /*--*/
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.sidebar.close  .logo {
    position: static;
    overflow: visible;
}

.sidebar.close .logo-details .logo_name {
    transition-delay: 0s;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links {
    height: 100%;
    color: #777777;
    padding: 30px 0 150px 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links {
    overflow: visible;
}

.sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links ul {
    padding: 10px 15px 0 0;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
/*
.sidebar .nav-links li{
  background: ; /*Color difuminado pegandole al azul del sombreado del menu #EBF5FF*/
/*} **/
.sidebar .nav-links li .iocn-link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li .iocn-link {
    display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li svg {
    height: 30px; /**/
    width: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    margin: 2px 15px;
    margin-right:  -4px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #777777;
 /*Esté cambia todo los colores de tanto iconos como de listado #3399ff */
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
.sidebar .sub-menu svg{
    margin:0px -100px;
}


.sidebar .nav-links:hover {
    color: #3399ff;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
/*LISTA PARA CAMBIAR TAMAÑO DE ICONOS DEL MENU SIDEBAR*/
.sidebar .nav-links li i{
    height: 43px;
    min-width: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
    color: #777777;
 /*Esté cambia todo los colores de tanto iconos como de listado #3399ff */
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}




.sidebar .link_name li:hover {
    color: #3399ff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  /*Esté cambia todo los colores de tanto iconos como de listado #3399ff*/
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links i.arrow {
    display: none;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li a {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 2px;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  /*border:dotted 1px red;*/
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #777777;
 /*Aquí va color gris pero de los titulos de cada Sub-Lista color a usar #3399ff proximamente*/
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li a .link_name {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #777777;
 /*Aquí va color gris pero de los titulos de cada Sub-Lista color a usar #3399ff proximamente*/
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 /*-Primer dato, segundo dato, Tamaño de Menu, Tamaño de lado izquierdo a derecha del SubMenu-*/
    margin-top: -10px;
    background: #fff;
 /*Aquí va el color del rectangulo que sale del menu*/
    display: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a {
    color: #777777;
 /*Color del titulo del sub menu del rectangulito*/
    font-size: 14px;
    margin:2px 4px;
 /*Cambiar tamaño del sub menu*/
    padding: 0 10px;
 /*Tamaño de distancia del sub menu*/
    font-weight: 500;
    white-space: nowrap;
  /*opacity: 0.6;*/
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


/**ESTA PARTE ES PARA EL HOVER ACTIVE**/
 .sidebar.close ul .active{
  background: #F2F2F2;
  margin:0 0 0 -3px;
  border-radius: 12px;
 }

 .sidebar.close li .active svg{
  color:#3399FF;
 }
 /*
 .sidebar.close ul .active a{
  color:#3399FF;
 }*/
 .sidebar.close li .active a{
  color:#3399FF!important;
 }
 .sidebar.close li .active svg{
  color:#3399FF!important;
 }
 .sidebar ul .active{
  background: #3399FF;
  margin:0 0 0 -5px;
 }
  .sidebar .nav-links .active span{
 color:#FFF!important;
}
.sidebar ul .active i{
 color:#FFF;
}


.sidebar li .active a {
 color:#fff!important;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .active svg{
 color:#FFF;
}
/**
ul li.active a{
    background: #262626;
    color:#fff;
}**/
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -2px;
    padding: 10px 20px ;
    font-weight: 500;
    
    border-radius: 0 12px 12px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu.blank {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    padding: 3px 20px 6px 16px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu.blank {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Agrega el CSS de tu código para que podamos reproducirlo y buscarte una solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código hace lo que pides, incluido lo solicitado en los comentarios:

```javascript
let arrow2 = document.querySelectorAll(".iocn-link");
for (var i = 0; i < arrow2.length; i++) {
  arrow2[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let arrow2Parent = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
    if(arrow2Parent.classList.contains("showMenu")) {
      closeall()
    } else {
      closeall()
      arrow2Parent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
    }
  });
}

function closeall() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrow2.length; i++) {
    let arrow2Parent2 = arrow2[i].parentElement;
    arrow2Parent2.classList.remove("showMenu");
  }
}
```

Lo que hacemos es comprobar si la que has pulsado está abierta, y mediante un condicional cerrarlas todas, o bien, si está cerrada cerramos todas pero abrimos la pulsada.

Aquí te dejo un snippet funcional que puedes ejecutar y ver como funciona:

```js
let arrow2 = document.querySelectorAll(".iocn-link");
for (var i = 0; i < arrow2.length; i++) {
  arrow2[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let arrow2Parent = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
    if(arrow2Parent.classList.contains("showMenu")) {
        closeall()
    } else {
        closeall()
      arrow2Parent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
    }
  });
}

function closeall() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrow2.length; i++) {
    let arrow2Parent2 = arrow2[i].parentElement;
    arrow2Parent2.classList.remove("showMenu");
  }
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.close {
  width: 78px;
}

.sidebar .Logo img {
  margin: 45px 0 10px -10px;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar .logo-details i {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #777777;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-width: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details i:hover {
  color: ;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #6e6b7b;
  /*--*/
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.sidebar.close .logo {
  position: static;
  overflow: visible;
}

.sidebar.close .logo-details .logo_name {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links {
  height: 100%;
  color: #777777;
  padding: 30px 0 150px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links {
  overflow: visible;
}

.sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links ul {
  padding: 10px 15px 0 0;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

/*
.sidebar .nav-links li{
  background: ; /*Color difuminado pegandole al azul del sombreado del menu #EBF5FF*/
/*} **/
.sidebar .nav-links li .iocn-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li .iocn-link {
  display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li svg {
  height: 30px;
  /**/
  width: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  margin: 2px 15px;
  margin-right: -4px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #777777;
  /*Esté cambia todo los colores de tanto iconos como de listado #3399ff */
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.sidebar .sub-menu svg {
  margin: 0px -100px;
}


.sidebar .nav-links:hover {
  color: #3399ff;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

/*LISTA PARA CAMBIAR TAMAÑO DE ICONOS DEL MENU SIDEBAR*/
.sidebar .nav-links li i {
  height: 43px;
  min-width: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #777777;
  /*Esté cambia todo los colores de tanto iconos como de listado #3399ff */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}




.sidebar .link_name li:hover {
  color: #3399ff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /*Esté cambia todo los colores de tanto iconos como de listado #3399ff*/
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links i.arrow {
  display: none;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li a {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 2px;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /*border:dotted 1px red;*/
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #777777;
  /*Aquí va color gris pero de los titulos de cada Sub-Lista color a usar #3399ff proximamente*/
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li a .link_name {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #777777;
  /*Aquí va color gris pero de los titulos de cada Sub-Lista color a usar #3399ff proximamente*/
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  /*-Primer dato, segundo dato, Tamaño de Menu, Tamaño de lado izquierdo a derecha del SubMenu-*/
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  /*Aquí va el color del rectangulo que sale del menu*/
  display: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a {
  color: #777777;
  /*Color del titulo del sub menu del rectangulito*/
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 2px 4px;
  /*Cambiar tamaño del sub menu*/
  padding: 0 10px;
  /*Tamaño de distancia del sub menu*/
  font-weight: 500;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*opacity: 0.6;*/
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


/**ESTA PARTE ES PARA EL HOVER ACTIVE**/
.sidebar.close ul .active {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  margin: 0 0 0 -3px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.sidebar.close li .active svg {
  color: #3399FF;
}

/*
 .sidebar.close ul .active a{
  color:#3399FF;
 }*/
.sidebar.close li .active a {
  color: #3399FF !important;
}

.sidebar.close li .active svg {
  color: #3399FF !important;
}

.sidebar ul .active {
  background: #3399FF;
  margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links .active span {
  color: #FFF !important;
}

.sidebar ul .active i {
  color: #FFF;
}


.sidebar li .active a {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .active svg {
  color: #FFF;
}

/**
ul li.active a{
    background: #262626;
    color:#fff;
}**/
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 500;

  border-radius: 0 12px 12px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu.blank {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  padding: 3px 20px 6px 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu.blank {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">

<ul class="nav-links">
  <li class="active arrow2">
    <div class="iocn-link">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="link_name">Página de Inicio</span>
      </a>
      <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow'>arrow</i>
    </div>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Página de Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Resumen de Actividad</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Editar Perfil</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Suscripciones</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cambiar contraseñas</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="iocn-link">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="link_name">Página Web</span>
      </a>
      <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow'>arrow</i>
    </div>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Página Web</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Selección de Plantilla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portada Banners</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portada - Contenido</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Distribución de Portada</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Páginas estáticas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Redes Sociales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gestión SEO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Configuración Sitio Web</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me sirvió :0
Aunque mi problema sigue siendo que me gustaría es que no solo con presionar al icono de flecha hiciera esa acción si no todo el elemento de la sub-lista

Comment: @InkizidorMelgarejo acabo de modificar mi respuesta con lo que has pedido. Básicamente el cambio es usar la clase `iocn-link` que abarca toda la linea, y en el evento usar `currentTarget` en lugar de `target`, y solo subir un nivel con `parentElement`

Comment: Muchas gracias :0 en serio muchas gracias me has salvado xD

Comment: Aunque una pregunta como lo puedo cambiar para que esté lo pueda abrir y cerrar al momento de dar click?
Osease que 1 click lo cierre y con otro lo abra?

Comment: @InkizidorMelgarejo Acabo de modificar mi respuesta con el comportamiento que solicitas. Compruébalo de nuevo.

Comment: ahora ya funciona perfecto muchas gracias :0
Una pregunta como puedo aprender más de esté tipo de cosas en Javascript?

Comment: Yo soy relativamente nuevo en javascript, desde que llegué aqui hace unos dos meses, y lo que me ayuda a responderos es ir a https://jsfiddle.net y pegar vuestro código y practicar con el buscando en google lo que no entienda.  Y usar mucho el `console.log` en distintos puntos del código para ver que va ocurriendo de forma certera... lo que yo llamo **seguir el código**.  Es decir, con esa herramienta, con google y con vuestras preguntas estoy aprendiendo una burrada en poco tiempo sin seguir nada realmente estructurado aun. Vosotros tambien me enseñais pues miro de entender lo que haceis.

Comment: oh vale muchas gracias :0 así intentare hacer
Aunque ahorita tengo otra duda no se si me puedas ayudar ahora con otra cosa de mi código es que ahora quisiera que el sidebar pudiera estar abierto cuando abra otra página no se si me pudieras ayudar así como en esté ejemplo de página que tengo
https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/ui/feather

Comment: No se que tengo que ver en ese enlace, la verdad, no entiendo lo que pides. De todos modos, para no mezclar cosas, y como este otro tema no tiene demasiado que ver con tu pregunta inicial, mejor que hagas una nueva pregunta especificando lo que quieres de tal forma que todos lo puedan entender (y yo tambien) y si veo factible ayudarte lo haré.